# MySQL insert specific value into column if two id from different tables match?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables **employees**, **managers**, **users**. I want to insert value 1 into **users** column **is_manager** only if the **id** from **employees** matches **id** from **managers**. **id** is primary key in **employees** and primary and foreign key in **managers**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN managers ON users.id=managers.id
SET users.is_manager=1
```

or

```
UPDATE users SET is_manager=1
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM managers
)
```

will do. I recommend the latter for better readability.